# Assign values to a list of lists

Tags: python, list, assign

I need to assign a predefined dimension to a list of lists. This is because the code within the `for` loop is using references to an '**existing**' array of such dimension and it would throw an '*index out of range*' error if the list is not preloaded before entering the loop.

The following slice of code intended to do such task does not produce the result I would expect.

```
a, b = 2, 3

matrix = [[[None]*2]*a]*b

for i in range(b):
    for j in range(a):
        print(i, j)
        matrix[i][j] = [i, j]
print(matrix)
```

I am expecting the elements of the two-dimension list of lists to be a two-elements list. Such as the print statement shows in the following output:

```
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
2 0
2 1
[[[2, 0], [2, 1]], [[2, 0], [2, 1]], [[2, 0], [2, 1]]]
```

The list of lists should contain the pairs printed.

Comment: related/(dupe?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: Thank you very much @Ch3steR, I did indeed look for the answer to this for several hours  before posting the question.

Comment: Don't use list multiplication, ever. Then you don't have to worry about the difference between a list of mutable values and a list of immutable values.

Comment: using list multiplication on another list will create multiple references to the same list object, so for example matrix[0][1] references the same list object as matrix[0][0]. Therefore, updating matrix[0][1] also updates matrix[0][0] (and everywhere else that it is referenced in matrix)

Comment: `[[[None for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(a)]for _ in range(b)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to pre-dimension the list of lists is as follows:

```
a, b = 2, 3

matrix = [[[None for _ in range(2)]  
                 for _ in range(a)]  
                 for _ in range(b)] 

for i in range(b):
    for j in range(a):
        print(i, j)
        matrix[i][j] = [i, j]
print(matrix)
```

So the output is as expected:

```
0 0
0 1
1 0
1 1
2 0
2 1
[[[0, 0], [0, 1]], [[1, 0], [1, 1]], [[2, 0], [2, 1]]]
```

Comment: Better still: `import numpy as np; matrix=np.full([2,a,b], None)`